# Finding the bottleneck in a set of trajectories

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, gaussian-process

I have some 2D data which looks like the following:

[image]

This can be seen as a plot of trajectories in 2D space, where the trajectories all pass through a point called the "bottleneck".  What I want to do, is to find the (x, y) values at this bottleneck point.

I have thought about the following ideas:

1) Fit a Gaussian process to the data, and then find the point of minimum variance. However, this will not necessarily be the bottleneck. In this example, the point of minimum variance is actually to the right of the bottleneck.

2) Do some clustering, e.g. k-means where k=2, to cluster the data points into two halves. Clustering could either be done in (x, y) space, or it could be done in (x, var) space, where "var" is the variance at point x along these trajectories. I could then find the point which lies right between these two clusters. However, I do not know how I would go about finding this point.

What is a good solution to this problem? Are my ideas valid, and if so, how could I solve the issues I have with them?

Comment: Are your trajectories noisy observations of graphs of $x$ (i.e. $y=f(x) + \text{noise}$) or could they be any 2d-curve (i.e. $(y(t) + \text{noise}, x(t) + \text{noise})$)

Comment: And what holds you back from identifying the bottleneck from a scatterplot as you did above?

Comment: I see a scatterplot of points, not a set of trajectories. Do you want to update your picture?

Comment: Why do you think Gaussians or k-means are good for this data? And not a density-based clustering? I do not see a Gaussian distribution here, not two k-means clusters. What about time?